# How to make Angular Forms ngModel classes inherit from Bootstrap Forms classes

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css, angularjs-directive

I am using Bootstrap 4 to style my form controls, and want to use the [Bootstrap Forms validation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#validation) styles when Angular's ngModel [adds CSS classes to forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms), such as `ng-valid, ng-invalid, ng-dirty, ng-pending`.

For example, if I have the following form

```
 <form novalidate>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" required />
 </form>
```

and want to apply Bootstrap's `.has-danger` class when the control fails data validation with Angular (i.e. when ngModel adds the class `.ng-invalid`). How do I accomplish this or something to the effect of

```
  input.ng-invalid {
    /* inherit from bootstrap's 
    .form-control-danger   */
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ng-class for applying the bootstrap classes. Bootstrap defines the styling of the classes once applied.

```
<form name='myForm'>
    <input type="email" name='input' class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" ng-class="myForm.input.$valid ? '' : 'has-danger' " required />
//or get fancy with the object argument form of ng-class
... ng-minlength='3' ng-class="{
      has-success: myForm.input.$valid,
      has-warning: myForm.input.$error.minlength,
      has-error: myForm.input.$error.required}"
```

Checkout: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Comment: Works. The `.has-danger` class is applied as expected. Whether  [Bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css), actually changes the visual presentation of the form element is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular2 you can use the same approach as the @Tyler answer but with the new syntax.

```
<div
    class="form-group"
    [ngClass]="{ 'has-success': user.valid, 'has-error': user.invalid}"
>
    <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="usr"
        name="usr"
        required
        #user="ngModel"
        [(ngModel)]="model.usr"
    >
</div>
```

You create a new variable named `user`, line `#user="ngModel"`, which contains the model state for user input. And with `[ngClass]="{ 'class-name': bool-expression}"` you assign classes when they expressions become true.

Have in mind that you need to put the classes names as strings if they aren't a valid JavaScript identifier (they have an `-` for example).